# Rundeck, disappearing lines in "Log Output"

Tags: c#, logging, rundeck

We have an issue with disappearing lines in "Log Output" with some jobs in Rundeck. Log output shows only 1st line of log and nothing more. And what is interesting, as you watch interactive running job log, you can see 2nd line in "log output" appears and after few second it disappears completely and nothing happens till the end of the job.
It's log of С# program running in windows environment. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: From Review: Your question lacks necessary information about your issue. Please read this to understand what is required to post a good question on S.O.: [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do you have minimal reproducible example, a job definition to test? Thanks!

Comment: Just usuall c# program, start in cmd with 2 keys. Nothing special, we have a lot of same jobs, with no problems in logs. Just wanna know, if some had have same problem somehow.

Comment: If you check the execution log you can see all the output?

Comment: Nope, it's same, only first string of logs..